# How to correct this script restore and recover database on Oracle?

Tags: oracle

this script to restore and recover the target database when we : Removed the target database to simulate and setup a disaster recovery situation, the instance is shutdown, and all the configuration files are in their appropriate places, my script is :

```
SQLplus> shutdown immediate
RMAN> STARTUP MOUNT
RMAN > SHOW ALL
RMAN > RESTORE DATABASE CHECK READONLY
RMAN > RECOVER DATABASE DELETE ARCHIVELOG
RMAN > ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS
```

at first we should create a read only tablespace called name_1
Shut down the database by using SQL plus tool :
Calling the recovery manager tool (RMAN) and make the database in mount mode.
Check the channels by using SHOW ALL statement
Applying the Restore statement with check read only
Applying the Recover statement
Start up the database in open mode

Comment: what is the problem when you tried this?

Comment: is this correct steps ? @kevinsky

Comment: Do you have an actual error or problem you are trying to solve or is this an interview question?

Comment: this is for  interview question @TheMadDBA